# Making Twitter Bootstrap 2.0's responsive layout completely fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The Twitter Bootstrap `2.0-wip` branch on GitHub includes a new responsive layout system. It's great for apps that need that level of responsiveness, but I'm developing a web-only app that needs to have a completely fixed layout.

Is there any *easy* way to override Bootstrap's responsive layout?

You can see it in action by cloning their repo, branching to `2.0-wip`, and opening `docs/scaffolding.html` in your browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `@media` queries found in the `bootstrap.css` file on line `2684`. That should eliminate all of the responsive qualities and just leave the standard  container width intact.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 940px) { ..... }
```

Comment: I thought it'd be that simple. The documentation made it seem like the `@media` queries weren't enabled by default, but maybe that's the *intention* that just hasn't been implemented yet (this is the wip branch, after all). Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Note, in 2.0.1+ the responsiveness has been moved to its own file, so it is turned off by default. To turn it on you include bootstrap-responsive.css or responsive.less.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: Just a note: in my case, it wouldn't work like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="twitter_bootstrap/less/responsive.less">` , I had to type `rel="stylesheet/less"` instead of just `rel="stylesheet"`. Like this `<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="twitter_bootstrap/less/responsive.less">`.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile your own custom bootstrap on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html, unticking the responsive features.

Alternatively you can include following file from BootstrapCDN: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css